# Extracting the column containing URL from a text file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have the file like this:

```
Timestamp       URL                    Text                    
1331635241000   http://example.com     Peoples footage at www.test.com,http://example4.com
1331635231000   http://example1.net    crack the nuts http://example6.com   
1331635280000   http://example2.net    Loving this
```

Each column is tab separated. I need to extract only the URLs from column 2 and column 3 if in case of the no URLs then leave it empty for example to get the result like this:

```
URL                    Text
http://example.com     www.test.com,http://example4.com 
http://example1.net    http://example6.com
http://example2.net
```

I tried this script

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $2,$3}' file | grep -oP '(((http|https|ftp|gopher)|mailto)[.:][^ >"\t]*|www\.[-a-z0-9.]+)[^ .,;\t>">\):]'
```

This script can give me the all  URLS in a single column without the header. Any suggestion to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it all in one awk script:

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==1 { print $2, $3; next }
{
    urls = ""
    while ( match($3,/((https?|ftp|gopher|mailto)[.:][^ >"\t]*|www\.[-a-z0-9.]+)/) ) {
        urls = (urls ? urls "," : "") substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $3 = substr($3,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print $2, urls
}
' file
URL     Text
http://example.com      www.test.com,http://example4.com
http://example1.net     http://example6.com
http://example2.net
```

I'm not convinced your RE for matching URLs is entirely accurate, you might want to look at that again.